# How to send photo, audio in telegram bot by using GmailApp.sendEmail?

Tags: java

```
function doPost(e){
  var data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  //Part 1
  if (data.message.text){
      var text = data.message.text;
      var id = data.message.chat.id;
      var name = data.message.chat.first_name ;
      var answer = "Hi " + name + ", thank you for your comment ";
      var answer2 = "Hi " + name + ", thank you for your comment " + "\n -----------\n " + text;
      sendText(id, answer);
      GmailApp.sendEmail(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail(), "Message send to Babak", answer2);
//Part 2
  } else if (data.message.photo) {
      var photo = data.message.photo;
      var text = data.message.text;
      var id = data.message.chat.id;
      var name = data.message.chat.first_name ;
      var answerToUser = "Hi " + name + ", thank you for your photo ";
      sendText(id, answerToUser);
      var answer2 = "Hi " + name + ", thank you for your comment " + "\n " + text; 
      GmailApp.sendEmail(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail(), answer2, photo );
  } else {
      var id = data.message.chat.id;
      var name = data.message.chat.first_name ;
      var answer = "Hi " + name + ",Only text message can be sent right now, photo, audio and video dev. is ongoing ";
      sendText(id, answer);
  }
}
```

Part 1 works fine, when i send only text message, but not Part 2.
Questions: From telegram bot I  send som photo.
The result I get from my gmail is:
why i do not get photon from my gmail?

Hi Babak, thank you for your comment undefined
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: please explain exactly what it is you're trying to do and provide a more complete example of how it goes wrong.